# Service Odoo 10 - Server odoo don't start properly

Tags: python, server, module, odoo

I wanted to stop my server that does not stop with the basic commands so I kill the service. Since when I run the server with the command: "service odoo start", the CSS, the images are not launched. Can you help me ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo restart
```

If it doesn't work , try along with `sudo service postgres restart`